# PHP how to split text that have same delimiter in the text?

Tags: php, split, explode, delimiter

I am having trouble to separate the text. 
This is the scenario:

`$check = "Apple|Orange|Animal|Dog|Grape";`

Suppose by using explode i could separate the word with "|", but because the value i retrieved "Animal|Dog" should be a word so in this case, what would be the solution?? I could not use 
limit as well because the position or number of text could be different.

The only way to distinctly separate the text is the Animal keyword. Is there any function in php that similar to mysql LIKE syntax?

If Case 2

```
$check = "Apple|Orange|Animal:Dog|Cat|Grape";
OR
$check = "Apple|Orange|Animal:Fish|Bird|Grape";
```

where the name of animal could be vary.
Output
`"Apple|Orange|Animal:Dog,Cat|Grape" or  "Apple|Orange|Animal:Fish,Bird|Grape"`

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us how you'd like the output to look?  You want each of those items to be separate or something more complicated?

Comment: I wanted to extract out "Animal|Dog" and change to "Animal:Dog" or the final output should be "Apple|Orange|Animal:Dog|Grape"

Comment: You only want to change this one string or any general string given the part to extract?

Comment: Only the particular string from Animal| to Animal:.
Eg: Animal|Cat|Banana|Orange = Animal:Cat|Banana|Orange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is replace "Animal|" with "Animal:" then you can do a simple [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
$check = "Apple|Orange|Animal|Dog|Grape";
$newCheck = str_replace("Animal|","Animal:"); // will be set to 'Apple|Orange|Animal:Dog|Grape'
```

Is that what you meant?

**EDIT, FOR CASE 2:**

I assume you have a string like `"Apple|Orange|Animal:Dog|Cat|Grape"`, which has the category followed by 2 members of the category.  From what you've said, you want to transform this string into `"Apple|Orange|Animal:Dog,Cat|Grape"` with a comma separating the two group members instead of a pipe.  This is more complicated than the first case - the category name could vary, and you can't do a simple `str_replace` starting with the colon because the first member of the group could vary as well.  For this case, you'll need to use a regular expression to match and replace the pattern of the string.  Here's the code:

```
$check = "Apple|Orange|Animal:Dog|Cat|Grape";
$newCheck = preg_replace("#(Animal:\w+)\|#", "$1,", $check); // will be set to "Apple|Orange|Animal:Dog,Cat|Grape"
```

[**DEMO**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d2ae089f00d22851809660b0344d3c1148f5913f)

Let me explain what this does, in case you're not familiar with regular expressions.  The first argument of the [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) function, `"#(Animal:\w+)\|#"`, tells PHP to look for all substrings of `$check` that begin with the text "Animal" followed by a colon, then a string of words with one or more character, and end with a pipe.  This will look for the category name as well as the first member of that category in your string.  The second argument, `":$1,"`, tells PHP to change the first pipe after this pattern into a comma.  If you have a different category name, simply change the pattern you pass as the first argument to the `preg_replace` function:

```
$check = "Apple|Orange|Animal1:Fish|Bird|Grape";
$newCheck = preg_replace("#(Animal1:\w+)\|#", "$1,", $check); // will be set to "Apple|Orange|Animal1:Fish,Bird|Grape"
```

Let me know if this is hard to follow!

Comment: Thanks Alex it does fix the issue.

Do you mind i ask, what if i wanted to extract the whole Animal|Dog|Cat, if in some case that it might be 'Animal|Dog|Cat'

Comment: You mean if you wanted to change `'Animal|Dog|Cat'` to `'Animal|Dog:Cat'`?  Then you'd do `$newCheck = str_replace("Animal|Dog|","Animal|Dog:");` instead.  Check out the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php).

Comment: Sorry typo
Lets say if by default is "Animal:Dog|Cat" or "Animal:Fish|Bird where the animal could be vary.

Comment: I'm still kind of confused at what you want to do.  You want to extract that section from the full string?  Or change it in some way?

Comment: Sorry for causing confuse, i had add in case 2 on top post. Please have a look.

Comment: I'm going to add another answer since this case is more complicated.

Comment: Do you want me to open another Topic?

Comment: It's fine, I'll post an answer here.  For case 2, will there only ever be a choice of two animals?  Or could there be more than 2?

Comment: Only 2, but for your information the 'animal' string could be vary as well. Eg. Animals:xx|xx / Animals1:xx|xx. But it will start with "Animal" and there will be only 2 animals.

Comment: I edited the above post in response to case 2, let me know if you have questions.

Comment: Thanks alot Alex !! You are very helpful. One more question wat is the '#' for ?? I can't find this on RegEx.

Comment: The `#` is a PHP [RegEx delimiter](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php).  I've gotten in the habit of using it instead of the forward slash since it makes the code look a bit neater.

Answer (score 0):

You have spaces between Apple and orange, like this Apple | Orange. But there is no space between Animal and Dog Like this Animal|Dog. If this is the situation, you can explode it like this

```
$check = "Apple | Orange | Animal|Dog | Grape";
$ex=explode(" | ", $check);
```

Which will return array in format

```
array("Apple","Orange","Animal|Dog","Grape");
```

You can manipulate above array again to get Animal

I hope this is what you meant

Edit : A rough solution could be :

```
<?
$check = "Apple|Orange|Animal|Dog|Grape";
$ex=explode("|",$check);
if(in_array("Animal",$ex))
{
    echo "Animal:";
}
if(in_array("Dog",$ex)){
    echo "Dog";
}
?>
```

So in this case the position of Animal and Dog doesnot matter

Comment: Ok sorry, in my case there is no space.

Comment: @Eric, What is your desired output?

Comment: I wanted to extract out "Animal|Dog" and change to "Animal:Dog"

Answer (score 0):

The way I would handle this would be to use a / instead of a | between categories and items. Or use a different delimiter if you really want to keep the | in between categories & items.

```
$check = "Apple|Orange|Animal/Dog|Grape";
$ex=explode("|", $check);
```

but if you don't want to do that... then if you know what your category names are like "animal", you could explode the array on | and assume that if your current value is "animal", then the next element in the array is going to be "dog", "cat", whatever. This is not a good solution though, and would not work for multiple category levels.

Comment: Oh, just saw your comment above. Probably the best bet is to explode the array and deal with the elements separately. Or you could try a string replace if you know what you're looking for. How many different categories will you have?

Answer (score -1):

str_replace("Animal|","Animal:",$check);
then do explode